# 12v driver 24v h-bridge

Tags: voltage, motor, h-bridge, short-circuit, mosfet-driver

[image]

Hi, I want to run a 24v motor with a 12v h-bridge mosfet driver (HIP4081A).
I haven't try it in real life but I made the schematic. I want to know before testing it if you can find any error or bad idea in my schematic.

I was successful to run the motor on 12v with the same battery than the driver.

Comment: [Rules and guidelines for drawing good schematics.](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/28251/rules-and-guidelines-for-drawing-good-schematics)  Very helpful for getting your ideas across.

Comment: You've copied and modified the circuit in the data sheet - where do you think this design might have gone wrong? I'm thinking that the 1N4002s are not going to be fast enough to provide adequate bootstrap voltage due to their crappy performance.

Comment: Looks good -- similar to p. 3 of the [HIP4081A datasheet](http://www.intersil.com/content/dam/Intersil/documents/hip4/hip4081a.pdf).

Comment: In fact I only want to know if how my batteries are setup is good, the circuit should be fine because I test it in 12v

Answer (score 1):

Whether your circuit is good depends on whether your 12 volt power supplies are fully isolated or not. While good ones usually are, if you're going with cheap Chinese models there is no guarantee - and just because the supply carries a sticker proclaiming that it conforms to some standard or UL doesn't mean it's true.

I suggest you test your power supplies to make sure that if you stack them there is no unwanted current flowing.

Comment: ok thanks for your post. In fact, I will use big 12v lead batteries, so there should be no problem